# Problems with READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: google-play

I’m trying to upload a version to the Play Store but strangely it tells me that error, looking on the internet says it’s just to modify the android Manifest and put ‘tools: node = “remove”’ in that same line to do them I can not do the prod release because when it compiles the files it re-adds the line but without the remove and it throws me errror.
Do not know how to remove that permission.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBnvm.png)

Comment: If you give a copy of your manifest and gradle file it might let us see where the permission is getting added. I suspect it will be one of the libraries you depend on. The solution is probably move to a newer version of the library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Actually the only thing I did was fill out a form in the Play Store